# Checking some work on differential $y''-4y=\sinh x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to check that I have done this correctly, because I feel like I am most of he way there but missing something important (or maybe just something obvious that I ought to know)

We have the following differential equation:

$$y''-4y=\sinh x$$

This should be simple enough, or so I thought. I see the characteristic equation for the linear homogeneous expression ($y''-4y=0$) should be $r^2 - 4 = 0$ so the roots are $r\pm2$.

All-righty then, the solution $y_p$ ought to look like this: $y_p = c_1e^{2x}+c_2e^{-2x}$ because both roots are real and distinct.

I take derivatives of $y_p$:

$$y'_p = 2c_1e^{2x}-2c_2e^{-2x}$$

$$y''_p = 4c_1e^{2x}+4c_2e^{-2x}$$

and plugging it back into the original DE:

$\sinh x = 4c_1e^{2x}+4c_2e^{-2x} - 4(c_1e^{2x}+c_2e^{-2x})$

But you can see the problem I end up with zero, and thus can't equate the coefficients of like powers (understand I had planned to just convert sinh into the Euler expression $\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$ and go from there).

So, I did something wrong, and it looks like I should have used variation of parameters here, but I admit that technique I am a bit fuzzy on. But if that's what I have to use...

Comment: Your $y_p=c_1e^{2x}+c_2e^{-2x}$ is just the homogeneous solution.  You need to find some $y$ so that $y''-4y=\sinh x$.  That will be your particular solution.  The final answer will then be $y+y_p$.

Comment: To find such a $y$ it would probably benefit you to write out the Euler expression.

Comment: Or reformulate into a system of two first order equations, but then you need to calculate the exponential of the system matrix.

Comment: Let me WolframAlpha it for you: [solve y''-4y=sinh x](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%27%27-4y%3Dsinh+x&x=-989&y=-72)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be that the homogenous solution $y_h=c_1e^{2x}+c_2e^{-2x}$, this satisfies the homogenous part $y''_h-4y_h=0$.

Now the particular solution $y_p$ should satisfy $y_p''-4y_p=\sinh x$, then the full solution $y=y_c+y_p$ must satisfy the ODE and the BCs.

Here $y_p=A\cosh x+B\sinh x$, then

$y''_p=A\cosh x+ B\sinh x=y_p$, so we get:

$y''_p-4y_p=-3A\cosh x-3A\sinh x=\sinh x$, so $B=0,A=-1/3$, thus $y_p=-\frac{1}{3}\sinh x$.

Now $y = c_1e^{2x}+c_2e^{-2x}-\frac{1}{3}\sinh x$

if you had BC's you would implement them at this point.

Comment: THanks - um, what are BCs? :-)

Comment: oh sorry, BC's are boundary conditions :)

Comment: :-) thanks that was funny...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a technique that Oliver Heaviside used for these problems: Rewrite your equation as
\begin{align}
\left(1 - \frac{1}{4}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}}{\mathrm{d}x^2} \right)y = -\frac{1}{4}\sinh(x)
\end{align}
You've already found $y_{h}$ (which this method won't find), so let's focus on $y_{p}$: Divide both sides by $\left(1 - \frac{1}{4}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}}{\mathrm{d}x^2} \right)$ to obtain
\begin{align}
y_{p}(x) &=-\frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{\left(1 - \frac{1}{4}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}}{\mathrm{d}x^2} \right)}\sinh(x) \\
&= -\frac{1}{4}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{4}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}}{\mathrm{d}x^2} \right)^{j} \sinh(x)  \\
&= -\frac{1}{4}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4^{j}} \sinh(x)  \\
&= -\frac{1}{3}\sinh(x)
\end{align}
Kinda fun, I guess.

Comment: It's cute, but it only works because of a lot of background that an elementary ODE course really can't cover. It also requires a nice expression for $\frac{d^{2n} f}{dx^{2n}}$, where $f$ is the RHS.